# Firefox update 58.0 causes refreshing tabs to grey out

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, firefox

After upgrading to Firefox version 58.0 this morning, a refresh of any tab causes Firefox to grey out (including Firefox sessions open in another work space).

Is there a way to correct this perhaps by going back to the previous working version before version 58.0 and how is this achieved?

Having research similar problems from a couple of years ago where the problem appeared to be associated with low ram, my PC has 4Gb, is 64 bit with intel® Celeron(R) CPU 847 @ 1.10GHz × 2 so I don't consider those previous questions/answers as relevant to this issue which has only occurred after the update this morning.

Comment: Did you report this bug?

Comment: @user535733 No, not as yet. Firefox is supported by Canonical, so that is why my question is posed here initially as others may have the problem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but not on other platforms.